# How to find the number of zeros in the left half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Given a rational function $P(s)/Q(s)$ with $deg(Q(s))\geq deg(P(s))$. How to show that $  Q(s)$ and $P(s)-Q(s)$ have same number of roots in the left half plane using Rouche's theorem?

> Instead of taking $deg(Q(s))\geq deg(P(s))$ if we consider $deg(Q(s))> deg(P(s))$ then can it be proved that $  Q(s)$ and $P(s)-Q(s)$ have **same number of roots** in the left half plane using Rouche's theorem?

Comment: You can't. Consider $Q(s) = (s+1)(s+2)$, and $P(s) = Q(s)+ (s-1)$. Some additional hypotheses are necessary.

Comment: The rational function has the property $P(0)=Q(0)$.

Comment: Still, choose $P(s) = Q(s) + s(s-1)$. And so far, the only thing $P/Q$ was used for was demanding that $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials.

Comment: $P(s)/Q(s)$ is the LST of a probability distribution function

Comment: LST is? Please add all relevant information/constraints. You need some stronger constraints to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: Laplace-Stieltjes transform of $F(t)$ is $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-st}dF(t)$